# Terminology for the difference of real dimension and scheme-theoretic dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Consider the scheme $\mathrm{Spec} \left(\mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2-a)\right)$ where $a$ is a real number. Scheme-theoretically, this has dimension $n-1$. But the dimension of the set of real points (as a manifold- I want to think about the analytic space associated to this scheme) doesn't always match this. When $a>0$, the real dimension is $n-1$, when $a=0$, the real dimension is 0, and when $a<0$, there are no real points.

Is there standard terminology for the difference between scheme-theoretic dimension and real dimension? Are there any works which treat this sort of dimension mismatch?