# How does one define a dimension of $V(F) = \{F = 0\}$ over the reals?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have questions about how dimension is defined for an affine varieties restricted to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $F(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, ..., x_n]$.

How does one define dimension for $V_{\mathbb{R}}(F) = V(F) \cap \mathbb{R}^n= \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n: F(\mathbf{x}) = 0  \}$?

One way to define this is to use the subspace topology (as a subspace of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$) and define it 
as the length of a maximal chain of irreducible closed sets (here closed sets are algebraic sets in $\mathbb{C}^n$ intersected with $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Another way I think is as the length of a maximal chain of irreducible algebraic sets (zero sets of real polynomials) in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

They both seem like a natural definition to me... Are these two possible definitions always give the same quantity if we are considering an algebraic set (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) defined by real polynomials?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know that zariski closed sets are precisely algebraic sets?

Comment: @Javi Yes, I do. But I guess I was wondering if the latter may have less closed sets in a way? as the latter only counts the algebraic sets defined by real polynomials while the former counts algebraic sets defined by complex polynomials as well (but then intersected with $\mathbb{R}^n$) and I was wondering if this affects things (such as dimension) or not...

Comment: If I'm understanding you well, the question would reduce to "Is there any complex polynomial with a real root that no real polynomial would have?" Because if you got a an algebraic set $V\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$, its intersection with $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives you the real roots of the polynomials of which $V$ was the zero set.

Comment: @Javi I guess to be very precise I think it reduces to "is there an algebraic set $V$ in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ such that $V \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ is not an algebraic set defined by real polynomials'', but maybe you mean the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always true that the scheme-theoretic dimension of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/(f_1,\cdots,f_k)$ is the Krull dimension of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb R[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/(f_1,\cdots,f_k)$ as a ring, which is equal to the Krull dimension of $\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/(f_1,\cdots,f_k)$ as a ring which is equal to the scheme-theoretic dimension of $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/(f_1,\cdots,f_k)$. This may be seen by considering what $-\otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$ does to chains of ideals.

On the other hand, the dimension of the $\Bbb R$ points need not behave so nicely. For $X\subset \Bbb A^n_{\Bbb R}$, the set of real points may have any dimension between $0$ and $n$: consider the variety cut out by $\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2$.

One saving grace is that if $X$ is a smooth $\Bbb R$ variety, then the dimension of the real points of $X$ as a manifold is either the algebraic dimension of $X$ or the set of real points of $X$ is empty. This may be seen by considering the Jacobian criteria for smoothness and the implicit function theorem. One can then upgrade this to say that a general variety has the expected dimension of it's real points if you can find a smooth point somewhere by considering $X^{sm}\subset X$.

Unfortunately, I've found that there's not even much standardized terminology about the mismatch of these dimensions - I searched diligently and asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353139/terminology-for-the-difference-of-real-dimension-and-scheme-theoretic-dimension) on this website nearly 3 years ago about the matter and it got no responses.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very nice answer! Just to relate it back to my question, does my first interpretation correspond to your first (using Spec), and when you talk about the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ points this is my second interpretation?

Comment: You are correct about your second interpretation. The equivalence of your first interpretation and my discussion about Spec should be equivalent if you're choosing the correct formulation of your interpretation - thinking about varieties as schemes is an equivalence as long as you do everything right.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm still struggling to see one point here that for $X$ smooth $\mathbb{R}$ variety its dimension as a manifold equals to its dimension as an $\mathbb{R}$ variety. I decided to make this into a separate question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165562/dimension-of-x-as-a-manifold-and-as-a-variety-are-they-the-same